# How to calculate mean of a double array with Collectors.averagingDouble?

Tags: java, java-8

I don't understand why the following code is not able to compile:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class AppMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        double[] x = {5.4, 5.56, 1.0};
        double avg = Arrays.stream(x).collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(n -> n));
    }
}
```

The error message is totally unclear.

```
The method collect(Supplier<R>, ObjDoubleConsumer<R>, BiConsumer<R,R>) in the type DoubleStream is not applicable for the arguments (Collector<Object,?,Double>)
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collector<Object,capture#1-of ?,Double> to Supplier<R>
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to double
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Arrays.stream(x)` for a `double` array returns a `DoubleStream`. The `DoubleStream` interface has different `collect` method than the `Stream` interface, and it doesn't accept a `Collector`.

You can simply use `average()` method of `DoubleStream`:

```
double avg = Arrays.stream(x).average().getAsDouble();
```

If you insist on using `avergingDouble` you'll need a `Stream<Double>`, which you can obtain by:

```
double[] x = {5.4, 5.56, 1.0};
double avg = Arrays.stream(x).boxed().collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(n -> n));
```

or by:

```
Double[] x = {5.4, 5.56, 1.0};
double avg = Arrays.stream(x).collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(n -> n));
```